# How create fonts in Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

How to create own fonts in Linux? 
Which software is use for it? 
 How to create fonts which can use everywhere Linux as well as windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io), it's in the repos.

```
sudo apt-get install fontforge
```

It comes with an online book about font design: [Design with FontForge](http://designwithfontforge.com).